# error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors

I have the below issue during the project compilation in VS2017:

**1>libPolyFill.lib(libPolyFill.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900' in clientPolyFill.obj**

The library file which was included in the project was compiled in VS2013 so I know that I need a specific Platform Toolset (V120) to compile it. But the problem is that Toolset V120 is no longer available even on microsoft site.
[I have only this toolset platforms to choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ymBY.png)
What can I do in this case?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Install Visual Studio 2013. Or recompile `libPolyFill.lib`

Comment: Where can I find VS2013 download source? On Microsoft official site it is not available anymore. Or how can I recompile lib file?

Comment: Where did you get the lib from? Perhaps the source code is available.

Comment: Seems like you can still get Visual Studio 2013 community here: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: The source code is not available anymore. Is it possible to recompile lib without source code?

Comment: No you can't do that.

Comment: When I tried to download VS2013 from your link I get the following message:Sorry, we couldn't find any downloads for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have the source code available (and therefore can't retarget `libPolyFill`), you're stuck using Visual Studio 2013.

Here's a SO answer with a direct download link to the ISO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31825881/1741450

Answer (score 5):

For people that google sends here for this type of error:

_MSC_VER is a linker check on whether the two objects linked are binary compatible. It was thankfully added after VC++ 2008 and has saved a lot of strange link errors.